# need a hand of a problem of my es_extended

Tags: items, drop, fivem, esx

gun or money. duplicated item props and text for all players and all player take items, money, guns. How to fix this problem? appear to all people though they would be los santos, palette bay or sandy shore no matter where i drop a item everyone can see it and there are not even close to me

we did try more es_exstendeds and each time we have that problem can some one explain or tell how this is happening!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.